# When user table gets a new record, create record in another table with user ID in .NET Core identity

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-identity

I have to code, When user table gets a new record, then automatically create record in `siteUSer` table with `userID` and `siteCodeId` in .net core.

`user` table does not have `siteCodeId` as a column. I need to add a record of `userId` with corresponding `siteCodeID` into `siteUSer` table.

```
public class SiteUsers 
{
    public int SiteCodeId { get; set; }
    public SiteCode SiteCode { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

This is `usersController.cs`:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(UserBO userBO)
{
    try
    {
        await _userService.CreateUserAsync(userBO);

        return Created(nameof(Get), userBO);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return HandleException(ex);
    }
}
```

This is `usersService.cs`:

```
public async Task<UserBO> CreateUserAsync(UserBO userBO)
{
    var user = new User
    {
        UserName = userBO.UserName,
        Email = userBO.Email,
        EmailConfirmed = true,
        RecordState = Enums.RecordState.Active,
    };    

    var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, userBO.Password);

    if (userBO.Roles.Count > 0)
    {
        // superadmin users can be created manually
        userBO.Roles = userBO.Roles.Where(i => i != "SuperAdmin").ToList();
    }

    foreach (var item in userBO.Roles)
    {
        await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, item);
    }

    return userBO;
}
```

Comment: So you are unable to assign role to user ?

Comment: @Harkiratsingh no that is not my problem. user is created and saved in user table. i need add a record to siteUser table with userID and siteId.

Comment: You can add to that table in the same method and fetch user id , I think siteId should be auto generated column?

Comment: Please show SiteCode schema , I think it will be saved first and then SiteUSers

Comment: you mean like this ` var siteUsers = new SiteUsers
            {
                UserId = userBO.UserId,
            };`

Comment: No , after the user is created , you can get user.Id and then after saving SiteCode you can fetch its id in codeId and then new SiteUser{UserId=user.ID,SiteCodeId=codeId};

Comment: @Harkiratsingh I tried to get userID  by using this code `var UserId = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);` but it gives error as `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'HttpContext.User' [Techne.Travel.Service.Identity]`. whtat is the issue. how can i get userID.

Comment: @hanushi Are you using EF Core? If not, what are you using for data persistence?

Answer (score 1):

You are performing three operations:

1. Create a new user
2. Add the user to some roles
3. Create a `SiteUsers` for the user

---

- Add the following methods for each of these operations in `UserService.cs`.
- Inject the `DbContext`(assuming you are using EF Core; if not, inject the equivalent service to add `SiteUsers` to the database). Use this service to add a new `SiteUsers` to the database.
- Also, you can use the email from the `UserBO` to look up an already created user.
- You don't even need to use a for loop to add a user to multiple roles, you can use `AddToRolesAsync()` that takes in an `IEnumerable<string>`:

```
public async Task<IdentityResult> CreateUserAsync(UserBO userBO)
{
    var user = new User
    {
        UserName = userBO.UserName,
        Email = userBO.Email,
        EmailConfirmed = true,
        RecordState = Enums.RecordState.Active,
    };

    return await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, userBO.Password);
}
```

```
public async Task CreateSiteUsersAsync(UserBO userBO, User user)
{
    SiteUsers siteUsers = new SiteUsers { UserId = user.Id, User = user };
    await _context.AddAsync(siteUsers);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

```
public async Task<IdentityResult> AddToRolesAsync(UserBO userBO, User user)
{
    if (userBO.Roles.Count > 0)
    {
        userBO.Roles = userBO.Roles.Where(i => i != "SuperAdmin").ToList();
    }

    return await _userManager.AddToRolesAsync(user, userBO.Roles);
}
```

```
public async Task<User> FindByEmailAsync(string email) => _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
```

Now, in your controller action, call each method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(UserBO userBO)
{
    try
    {
        //Create user
        IdentityResult createUserResult = await _userService.CreateUserAsync(userBO);
        if(!createUserResult.Succeeded)
        {
            //Handle error
        }

        //Find created user
        User user = await _userService.FindByEmailAsync(userBO.Email);
        if(user is null)
        {
            //Handle error
        }

        //Add to roles
        IdentityResult addToRolesResult = await _userService.AddToRolesAsync(userBO, user);
        if(!addToResult.Succeeded)
        {
            //Handle error
        }

        await CreateSiteUsersAsync(userBO, user)

        return Created(nameof(Get), userBO);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return HandleException(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you . sme as this idea, i need to write inside only one funtion.  `public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] UserBO userBO, [FromBody] SiteCode siteCode){}` like this. but i got error `Only one parameter per action may be bound from body. Inspect the following parameters, and use 'FromQueryAttribute' to specify bound from query, 'FromRouteAttribute' to specify bound from route, and 'FromBodyAttribute' for parameters to be bound from body:
UserBO userBO
SiteCode siteCode`

Comment: @hanushi `[FromBody]` cannot be applied to multiple parameters since the request stream is not available after it is read once. You could create another view model class containing two properties of type `UserBO` and `SiteCode`  and have that as the parameter.

Comment: @hanushi Good to know. Make sure to encourage answerers of all helpful answers with upvotes or accepting answers :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, which would also fix the problem of getting the user id from the web request context.

1. Create an API service `SiteUserService`, that allows you to add site users.
2. Inject the data context and HTTP context.
3. Create a method `CreateSiteUser()` that takes the site code id and generates the `SiteUser` record.
4. Call API service `SiteUserService` method `CreateSiteUser()` from the web client.
   The `CreateSiteUser()` method can be included within an existing or new controller method.

The service class `SiteUserService` is shown below:

```
public class SiteUserService
{
    private readonly HttpContext _context;
    private ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public SiteUserService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, 
        ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _context = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
        _db = db;
    }

    public async Task CreateSiteUser(int siteCodeID)
    {
        var siteUser = new SiteUsers
        {
            SiteCodeId = siteCodeID, 
            SiteCode = new SiteCode()
            {
                // set your site code properties in here..
            },
            UserId = _context.Request.HttpContext.User.Id,
            User = new User()
            {
                // set your user properties in here
                // e.g. _context.Request.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name
            }
        };

        _db.Add(siteUser);
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();               
    }

    ...
}
```

The `SiteCode` and `User` object properties can be populated as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code , it should work

```
var userName=UserBPO.email;
var user=_userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);// You can use FindByEmailAsync as well
if(user!=null)
{
//Assign the role and populate SiteUsers
//Save SiteCode to database and get its ID in siteId
SiteUsers siteUsers = new SiteUsers { UserId = user.Id, SiteCodeId=siteId };
await _context.AddAsync(siteUsers);
}
```

Comment: Please try this , it should work as expected

Comment: Please accept this answer if it helped you so that it can be helpful to others